# Run command in new gnome-terminal and .bashrc

Tags: gnome-terminal, bashrc

I'm trying to launch one command in a new `gnome-terminal` window from a shell script, and it seems that my `.bashrc` file doesn't get sourced when calling gnome-terminal and executing a command:

```
gnome-terminal -t "my title" -e vim
```

But it does when launching `gnome-terminal` alone:

```
gnome-terminal -t "my title"
```

(for testing purposes, just add a `echo "something"` to the end of the `.bashrc`)

I also tried explicitly sourcing the `.bashrc` before running `vim` with no success:

```
gnome-terminal -t "my title" -x $SHELL -c "source $HOME/.bashrc; vim"
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem with the help of [this reply](https://askubuntu.com/a/77053/33598).

Actually the `.bashrc` was sourced, but not completely processed because of the following lines:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

To bypass the problem, the cleanest approach would be to force the shell instance to be run in interactive mode (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4350185/831797)):

```
gnome-terminal -t "my title" -x $SHELL -ic "vim"
```

Comment: careful that will break things user wide.

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

No, your are correct. gnome-terminal does not source .bashrc when running a command via the -e argument.

Bash and gnome-terminal are two separate things. When you run without -e gnome-terminal runs your default shell (which happens to be bash). When you run with -e gnome-terminal runs the command you provided (bash is not loaded so .bashrc is not sourced).

Your last example will not work either. $HOME is a variable in bash and not available. In addition source is a bash command, and vim likely needs a path.

The best way to do this, in my opinion is to make a wrapper script.

In your path somewhere (I added ~/.bin/ to my path) create a file called vim-x and set it executable.

> #!/bin/bash
>   source $HOME/.bashrc
>   vim "$@"

Then you can run:

`gnome-terminal -t "my title" -e /home/user/.bin/vim-x`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this approach and it still doesn't work (no `echo "something"` in the new gnome-terminal window)