# What is dpkg-reconfigure and how is it different from dpkg --configure?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I was recently given an answer to another question [Help: “aptd” is maxing out my CPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589840/help-aptd-is-maxing-out-my-cpu) which included running the commands

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a
```

and

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

That all seems reasonable but I was curious about a few things.

What is `dpkg-reconfigure` and what do the `-phigh -a` flags mean?

How is it different from `dpkg --configure`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [`man dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)

```
   --configure package...|-a|--pending
          Configure a package which has been unpacked but not yet  config‐
          ured.   If  -a  or  --pending  is  given instead of package, all
          unpacked but unconfigured packages are configured.

          Configuring consists of the following steps:

          1.  Unpack  the  conffiles, and at the same time back up the old
          conffiles, so that they can be restored if something goes wrong.

          2. Run postinst script, if provided by the package.
```

From [`man dpkg-reconfigure`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/dpkg-reconfigure.8.html)

```
   dpkg-reconfigure - reconfigure an already installed package

   -pvalue, --priority=value
       Specify the minimum priority of question that will be displayed.
       dpkg-reconfigure normally shows low priority questions no matter
       what your default priority is. See debconf(7) for a list.

   -a, --all
       Reconfigure all installed packages that use debconf. Warning: this
       may take a long time.
```

Here `dpkg --configure -a` will configure all unpacked but unconfigured packages. whereas `dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a` will reconfigure all installed packages that use `debconf` with high priority.

Comment: Please be warned that the "-a"  "--all" options are not available since 15.10 release and up, as I found trying to use it on 16.04.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/775328/is-dpkg-reconfigure-all-still-available-in-16-04

Comment: I'm still a tad confused, though. So what exactly does dpkg-reconfigure do to the package when it "reconfigures" it? I saw the first answer where it says dpkg-reconfigure on this site:https://superuser.com/questions/1153203/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-resolved-dns-lookups-randomly-fail/1200745#1200745. What happens to resolvconf when it's reconfigured?