# Is `dpkg-reconfigure --all` still available in 16.04?

Tags: dpkg, configure

After upgrading to 16.04, I tried to use that command, but it seems that `dpkg-reconfigure` (or `dpkg --reconfigure`) doesn't understand the option `--all`.

Is it still available? If not, is there an equivalent command?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not equivalent, but probably what you are looking for if you want to be sure, everything is at least somehow configured:

`dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Doesn't work on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 16):

You can try this script:

```
(
    for i in `dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | awk '{print $2}'`; do
        echo $i; sudo dpkg-reconfigure $i;
    done
) 2>&1 | tee dpkg-reconfigure.log
```

It reconfigures all installed packages and saves the log to `dpkg-reconfigure.log` file.

Comment: This doesn't work if any of the packages have a full screen dialog pop up where you have to choose "Yes" or "No". The keyboard doesn't select the options.

Comment: @Mike, when you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure` just for the package showing the screen dialog, does the keyboard work correctly that way?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: Thanks, @Mike. And when you try these: 1. `(sudo dpkg-reconfigure YOUR_PACKAGE)` when the command is enclosed in braces, or 2. `(sudo dpkg-reconfigure YOUR_PACKAGE) 2>&1`, or 3. `(sudo dpkg-reconfigure YOUR_PACKAGE) 2>&1 | tee dpkg-reconfigure.log`, which of those work and which don't?

Answer (score 2):

No, `dpkg-reconfigure` on 16.04 (but also on 15.10) does not have the option `--all` any more, although it was present in 14.04 (not sure about 14.10).

You could have verified that yourself by checking the command's manpage:

```
man dpkg-reconfigure
```

On a 16.04 (or 15.10) system, this manual page will not list an `--all` argument, while on 14.04 one is present.

If you don't have those systems at hand, just read the online manpages: [16.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/dpkg-reconfigure.8.html) - [15.10](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man8/dpkg-reconfigure.8.html) - [14.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/dpkg-reconfigure.8.html)
(note for future readers: if one of the linked releases has reached end-of-life by the time you read this, the link will redirect to the latest release's manpage instead of showing the old, archived version)