# Reset the whole system

Tags: command-line, system-installation, system

I use UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS, with all the Gnome desktop enviroment ("by my hand" installed with Synaptic).

I wonder if there is a simple way (line command) to get a full, whole system reset to its factory settings, without to have to install it from the Live CD.

Why I don't want to install it from the Live CD? Simple... Unfortunately, the home directory would be lost if I do that, and I have a lot of personal data in that directory.

BTW: I think future versions of Ubuntu should leave the user personal data (audio, video, image, text, etc) in another partition, by default, to avoid this issue. Just an Idea.

So... Is there some simple command to reset the whole system to the factory setting parameters?

Comment: Juan - this may also be helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/775328/is-dpkg-reconfigure-all-still-available-in-16-04 {Is `dpkg-reconfigure --all` still available in 16.04?}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to get what you want.

- Copy the home directory to a separate disk
- Reinstall Linux
- Mount the disk with your home data under /home

Exactly what you suggested, not for future Ubuntu versions but for your future installations.

Comment: I see! But.. I insist, there should be an automatic way, inside the Ubuntu installation process, which put the "home" directory into a full separated partition (not the system one) by default, to avoid any data loss.