# How to configure lots of packages afterwards

Tags: apt, configuration, unattended-upgrades

During unattended-upgrades (--verbose) I get this for each upgraded package: `debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed`

How to deal with this? I installed apt-utils thereafter, but that does not make my packages properly configured as such.

P.S. I noticed that apt-utils was removed long time ago together with ubuntu-minimal when I tested newer version of apt from focal-proposed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dpkg-reconfigure` to (re)configure already-installed packages. You can use the `-a (--all)` flag to reconfigure all packages, or specify the package you want to configure. For other available options, see the [dpkg-reconfigure man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/dpkg-reconfigure.8.html).

Comment: `-a (--all)` has been unknown option for long time, though it still is present as tab-completion. https://askubuntu.com/q/775328/21005