# Can not install Wine on Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, lubuntu, wine, dependencies

I am not able to meet all the dependencies needed to install Wine.

I have followed all the instructions as on [the Ubuntu page on the WineHQ wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).

But when I do `sudo apt install winehq-stable`, my computer shows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 4.0.4~focal)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then when I do `sudo apt install wine-stable`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 4.0.4~focal) but 5.0.0~eoan is to be installed
               Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 4.0.4~focal)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then when i do `sudo apt install wine-stable-amd64 wine-stable-i386`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wine-stable-amd64 is already the newest version (5.0.0~eoan).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.16) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgphoto2-port12:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: liblcms2-2:i386 (>= 2.2+git20110628) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libmpg123-0:i386 (>= 1.13.7) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libopenal1:i386 (>= 1.14) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libpcap0.8:i386 (>= 0.9.8) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libudev1:i386 (>= 183) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libvkd3d1:i386 (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                  libopencl1:i386
                         Depends: ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                  libopencl-1.1-1:i386
                         Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libncurses6:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                  libncurses5:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                  libncurses:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libcapi20-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libdbus-1-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libglu1:i386
                         Recommends: libgnutls30:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libgnutls28:i386 but it is not installable or
                                     libgnutls26:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libgsm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libjpeg62-turbo:i386 but it is not installable or
                                     libjpeg8:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libkrb5-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libpng16-16:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libpng12-0:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libsane1:i386
                         Recommends: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libtiff5:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libv4l-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxcomposite1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxcursor1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxfixes3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxi6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxrandr2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxrender1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I see you have held broken packages; usually meaning a prior command didn't complete successfully and needs to be fixed first (often a `sudo apt -f install` can fix unless your sources have been polluted with inappropriate sources intended for other OS/release).  I do note mention of eoan/19.10 sources, so you may have polluted your sources (unless you recently upgraded from eoan, though they should have been disabled during upgrade).

Comment: You possibly have a mix of repositories. Please add output of `apt-cache policy winehq-stable wine-stable` to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Have you enabled 32 bit on your PC? Enter this command to do that: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and try again. Good luck!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands to fix the error:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If this fails, you can view the list of held packages by typing:

```
sudo apt-mark showhold
```

and then you can unhold them by typing:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <dodgy-package>
```

And then run the `dpkg --configure -a` command, and `sudo apt-get update`.  If this *still* doesn't work, use `aptitude`, which I use because it is smarter than `apt-get`, and helps deal with conflicting packages.  Install like this:

```
sudo aptitude install wine
```

Cheers!