# wine1.6-i386:i386 : Depends: wine1.6:any (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14)

Tags: package-management, wine, dependencies

I have a problem with Wine. I can't install software and I these results:

```
kamdem@kamdem-HP-EliteBook-8470p:~$ sudo apt-get --download-only dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading status information... Done
You can run 'apt --fix-broken install' to fix these problems.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6
 wine1.6-amd64: Depends: wine1.6:any (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14)
                Recommends: libp11-kit-gnome-keyring but it is not installed
                Recommends: libpng12-0 but it is not installed.
                Recommended: unixodbc
                Recommends: wine-gecko2.21 but it is not installed.
                Recommended: wine-mono0.0.8 but it is not installed.
 wine1.6-i386:i386: Depends: wine1.6:any (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14)
                    Recommends: libgif7:i386 but it is not installed.
                    Recommends: libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 but it is not installed.
                    Recommends: libpng12-0:i386 but it is not installed.
                    Recommends: libxt6:i386 but it's not installed
                    Recommends: p11-kit-modules:i386 but it is not installed
                    Recommended: unixodbc:i386
                    Recommends: wine-gecko2.21:i386 but it is not installed.
                    Recommended: wine-mono0.0.8:i386
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' without a package.
(or provide a solution).
```

Comment: Do you have -updates listed in your sources (I assume you're using 16.04/xenial; a package listed in your message looks out-dated, so I'd check your sources). https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=wine ; you should tell us the release for more accurate responses too.

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240184/can-not-install-wine-on-lubuntu-20-04/1240237#1240237

Answer (score 1):

I don't know French but I think I have understood your problem.

You are have problems with package dependencies. To solve this problem, do following:

#### 1. **Update Repository Information**

It is a preparatory for step 2. You need to update APT repository information. If you don't, chances are that your problem won't resolve. To do this type following in terminal and hit enter:

```bsh
sudo apt update
```

#### 2. **Fix Dependency Problem**

To solve the cause of problem, this step is a must. You are having package dependency problem. On most cases, APT can fix these types of problems. To do that
type following on terminal and hit enter:

```bsh
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

#### 3. **Retry and do whatever you want to do**

The problem is fixed. You can now upgrade all packages with your command. Or you can do whenever you like to do on your Ubuntu.