# Kubuntu won't boot after I interrupted Update

Tags: boot, updates, kubuntu

Today I interrupted my Kubuntu update and now it doesn't run. I get the below error message. I need the data on this.

My system is a dual boot with Windows 7

[image: error message]

---

I tried Karsus' answer but I still have issues.

I managed to boot from a live USB with Kubuntu(14.04). I enter the console and gave following commands.

```
    sudo -s
    mkdir /data1
    fdisk -l (my partition is called sda6)
    mount /dev/sda6 /data1
    chroot/data1
```

and then I followed your commands, beginning with

```
    sudo dpkg --configure -a
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a

    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -f
    sudo apt-get autoclean
    sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The system worked, but it doest solved my problem. It is still the same error message.

It doesnt disturbe me, if i have to set up everything, but at least i want to save all data from the partition

P.S. I can start from an older version of my kernel, but it gives me the same error message

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

1. When starting your PC, go into the grub menu. If that doesn't happen automatically because of dual boot, you can do it by [holding SHIFT](https://askubuntu.com/a/82145/498541). Once you are in the grub GUI menu, select an older kernel than the one you were using to boot.

If 1 doesn't work:

2. Boot your system with a live USB.
3. Back up up all your data. You can move them to another partition, or - better - to an external hard drive.

After backing up all your data you have two options:

1. Reinstall the OS.
2. Try to repair your package installation.

---

**Edit**: Adding Hi-Angel's suggestion.

You can also try to repair your installation from a live USB. After booting, you will need to mount the drive where Kubuntu is located. The below is written assuming it's mounted at `/dev/media`. If not, change the below lines appropriately.

```
sudo -s
mkdir /media/Ubuntu
mount /dev/media /media/Ubuntu 
cd /media/Ubuntu
mount -t proc /proc proc 
mount --rbind /sys sys
mount --rbind /dev dev
mount --rbind /run run
chroot /media/Ubuntu /bin/bash
```

After that, proceed as if you had booted from old kernel.

---

You can try to repair (assuming you managed to boot from an older kernel) with:

```
sudo -s # If you haven't already from live usb
dpkg --configure -a
dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a
```

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/590912/498541) to read what these commands do.

For good measure you can also run these:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -f
apt-get autoclean
apt-get autoremove
```

If everything worked, reboot and load the latest kernel.

If something goes wrong and assuming you want to rescue your system instead of re-installing you can then remove the offending kernel following suggestions from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu). Reboot after removing and then run the update process normally to re-install it.

Comment: ⁺¹ though, but you omitted an important step, before running `dpkg` commands they have to mount to LiveCD *procfs*, *tmpfs*, etc. [Here's, in the end of paragraph](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_existing_Linux#Method_A:_Using_the_bootstrap_image_.28recommended.29), an example of mount commands. I actually think, reinstalling kernel would be enough.

Comment: Aw, you probably meant to run them from rescue prompt, sorry, I thought it goes about LiveUSB.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thank you for your comment. I only meant the dpkg commands to run if he can boot from an older kernel. You are right that he would need to do additional work to do it from a live USB but I do not know enough about it to describe it. And unfortunately I didn't understand enough from your link to add that procedure as well. I think some commands may need to be altered a bit (e.g. cd /tmp/root.x86_64).

Comment: Right; I think it would be: 1. Mount the Ubuntu, e.g., to `/media/Ubuntu`, then *(with elevated priveledges)*: `mount --bind /media/Ubuntu /media/Ubuntu && cd /media/Ubuntu && mount -t proc /proc proc && mount --rbind /sys sys && mount --rbind /dev dev && mount --rbind /run run && chroot /media/Ubuntu /bin/bash`.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thanks for clearing that up. I added your suggestion. I broke the commands so if he gets an error it's easier for him to see after which command it happened and tell us.

Comment: You don't need `--bind` to mount a drive. And btw, I'd recommend to remove all `sudo ` from the post, and just to note that before commands one ought to run `sudo -s` to get elevated privileges. That would allow simple copy-paste, because ATM one need to write a password after the first `sudo`, which isn't obvious for a newbie.