# Command not found after setting source in bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, source

Following the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04), and everything works fine manually. However, when I use the instructions in a bash script, I get `rbenv command not found` because the `source ~/.bashrc` didn't execute correctly. What's going on? Feel like I've run into this before on something else...

*Execute bit is set, ran dos2unix, and have `#!/bin/bash` at the top.

```
#!/bin/bash

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
rbenv install 2.3.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because the script subshell doesn‘t run interactively, in which case the `~/.bashrc` is set to do nothing by default. You can either use any of the workarounds explained in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041348/507051) and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/77053/507051) or simply call `rbenv` with the full path on the last line:

```
$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv install 2.3.1
```

Note that for Cosmic onwards there’s [an `rbenv` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/rbenv) in the repositories.