# How can I reload bashrc in a script and not failing?

Tags: 20.04, bash, bashrc

I have written a script that downloads and installs anaconda3, and some other dependencies, and then it installs a couple of python modules using `pip3`.
The issue is that my `source ~/.bashrc` doesn't seem to work, and thus `pip3`'s are not recognized. If I use `exec bash`, the remaining instructions after this command are not executed.
What should I do?
This is my script by the way :

```
#!/bin/bash

## Bash script for setting up a PX4 development environment on Ubuntu LTS (16.04 and above).
## It can be used for installing simulators (only) or for installing the preconditions for Snapdragon Flight or Raspberry Pi.
##
## Installs:
## - Common dependencies and tools for all targets (including: Ninja build system, latest versions of cmake, git, anaconda3, pyulog)
## - jMAVSim simulator dependencies
## - PX4/Firmware source (to ~/src/Firmware/)

# Preventing sudo timeout https://serverfault.com/a/833888
trap "exit" INT TERM; trap "kill 0" EXIT; sudo -v || exit $?; sleep 1; while true; do sleep 60; sudo -nv; done 2>/dev/null &

# Ubuntu Config
echo "Remove modemmanager"
sudo apt-get remove modemmanager -y
echo "Add user to dialout group for serial port access (reboot required)"
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER

# Update CMake and Git
# Installing latest version of cmake (ref https://askubuntu.com/questions/355565/#865294 )
echo "Installing latest version of CMake"
sudo apt update && \
sudo apt install -y software-properties-common lsb-release && \
sudo apt clean all
wget -O - https://apt.kitware.com/keys/kitware-archive-latest.asc 2>/dev/null | gpg --dearmor - | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/kitware.gpg >/dev/null
sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs) main"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kitware-archive-keyring
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/kitware.gpg
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cmake

# Installing the latest version of git
echo "Installing the latest version of git"
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git -y

# Install anaconda3
type conda >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "Installing anaconda3 (python 3.8.8)"; wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh; bash ./Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh;}

source ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc

# Common dependencies
echo "Installing common dependencies"
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install git zip cmake build-essential genromfs ninja-build exiftool astyle -y
# make sure xxd is installed, dedicated xxd package since Ubuntu 18.04 but was squashed into vim-common before
which xxd || sudo apt install xxd -y || sudo apt-get install vim-common --no-install-recommends -y
# Required python packages
pip3 install argparse empy toml numpy
pip3 install pandas jinja2 pyserial pyyaml
pip3 install pyulog

# jMAVSim simulator dependencies
echo "Installing jMAVSim simulator dependencies"
sudo apt-get install ant openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre -y
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems it doesn't cause any issues, as it downloads and installs it just fine(though I fixed it already thanks to you). the double sourcing is just there since sourceing once didnt do anything. the two of them also dont do any good either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `eval` to source `~/.bashrc` successfully. I did this :

```
eval "$(cat ~/.bashrc | tail -n +10)"
```

Quoting from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041348/497851):

> This behavior is specific to Ubuntu (and probably most derived
> distros), since your default `~/.bashrc` file starts with a
> short-circuit, Ubuntu 18.04, for
>
> example:
>
> ```
> # If not running interactively, don't do anything
> case $- in
>     *i*) ;;
>       *) return;;
> esac
> ```
>
> ...That will stop the evaluation of the file if it is running in a
> non-interactive shell, which is the case of your script since all
> scripts are run in a non-interactive shell, and subsequently every
> file you source will inherit this property.

and all went just fine. It seems since scripts run in non-interactive mode, sourcing `bashrc` doesnt have any effect because of a check at the beginning of the bashrc (at least in ubuntu based distros). therefore using eval, we can circumvent this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following code after `source ~/.bashrc`, which makes Bash forget all remembered full-paths:

```bsh
$ hash -r
```

[From Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands):

> hash [-r] [-p filename] [-dt] [name]
>
> Each time hash is invoked, it remembers the full pathnames of the commands specified as name arguments, so they need not be searched for on subsequent invocations. [...] The -r option causes the shell to forget all remembered locations.